# How to change the value of attribute in xmlstarlet

Tags: android, android-manifest, xmlstarlet

I want to setup a script to change values and keys on android manifest during production build.
This is the manifest (removed unnecessary code for simplicity)

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.sample">
      <application android:name=".MainApplication" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:allowBackup="false" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <!-- Branch keys -->
        <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="key_test_ad82b98f289hfhfoBxfzSNXq"/>
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

I simply want to change the Branch key with the production one, eg: `key_live_0932nfe9hfbf`
I have tried this

```
xmlstarlet edit --inplace --update "/manifest/application/meta-data[@android:name='io.branch.sdk.BranchKey']/@android:value" --value "test" $thisDirectory/../android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml
```

and get this output

```
Undefined namespace prefix: /manifest/application/meta-data[@android:name='io.branch.sdk.BranchKey']/@android:value
Invalid expression: /manifest/application/meta-data[@android:name='io.branch.sdk.BranchKey']/@android:value
```

when I remove the latest part of xPath `@android:value` it works but nothing is changed (of course).

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: @urcodebetterznow sorry it was a mistake while slimming the file to paste it here, When I ran the command it was the whole file and it contains the `<application>`. Fixed the question

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate your problem, for some reason, but this seems to be a namespace problem. Try changing your `--update` parameter to

```
-update "/manifest/application/meta-data[@android:name='io.branch.sdk.BranchKey']/@*[local-name()='value']"
```

and see if it works.